# In Node.js/Express, how do I automatically add this header to every "render" response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, url

I have many of these "controllers":

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    var stuff = { 'title': 'blah' };
    res.render('mytemplate',stuff);
});
```

Notice res.render? I want to add this header to every response header I make:

`X-XSS-Protection: 0`

How can I add that response header automatically?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
// global controller
app.get('/*',function(req,res,next){
    res.header('X-XSS-Protection' , 0 );
    next(); // http://expressjs.com/guide.html#passing-route control
});
```

Just make sure this is the first controller you add, order is significant.

Comment: aahh, this one seems even better

Comment: if you really want to add the header argument to all calls this is way shorter than to add the middleware call to every route.

Comment: So by adding this as the first controller, all my other controllers will have that header inside their response?

Comment: Afaik yes, so it's possible to route a response through several controllers.

Comment: This is out of date now, see below.

Comment: What does the `next()` function call do? It works without it, so I was just kind of curious

Comment: Plz look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69409586/how-to-make-a-get-call-to-api-github-with-express-server

Answer (score 84):

You probably want to use [app.use](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) with your own middleware:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('X-XSS-Protection', 0);
    next();
});
```

Comment: This is what everyone should be using now.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go in Express 4. Always use `app.use`

Comment: Much better than the excepted answer.

Comment: Note `res.set` [is an alias](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set) is the function for which the method used here -- `res.header`  -- is an alias

Answer (score 15):

For express 4.x, the idiomatic way is as follows:

#### Implementation

```
// no mount path; executed for every request.
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.set('X-XSS-Protection', 0);
  next();
});
```

#### Test

```
describe('Response Headers', function () {
  it('responds with header X-XSS-Protection: 0', function (done) {
    hippie(app)
    .get('/any/route/you/can/think/of')
    .expectHeader('X-XSS-Protection', 0)
    .end(done);
  });
});
```

#### Dev Dependencies (for tests to work)

```
% npm install --save-dev mocha hippie
```

#### Relevant Documentation

- [Application Level Middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application)
- [res.set](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.set)

Answer (score 7):

you could create your own middleware method like so:

```
addToHeader = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log("add to header called ... " + req.url);
  res.header('X-XSS-Protection', '0');
  next();
}
```

and then change your routes to sth like this:

```
app.get('/', addToHeader, function(req,res){
  var stuff = { 'title': 'blah' };
  res.render('mytemplate',stuff);
});
```

should work.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)...

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next()
})
```

But make sure you use it **before** your API method. Like this:

```
const app = express()

// middleware
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next()
})

// api
app.get('/user', (req, res, next) => {
  service.doSomething
    .then(data => res.send(data))
    .catch(next)
})

app.use(handleError)
```

Took me a while to figure it out. I didn't see it mentioned anywhere so adding this to complement previous answers.

Comment: can you plz look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69409586/how-to-make-a-get-call-to-api-github-with-express-server

Answer (score 3):

I find that another good place to inject default headers is during the Routing Middleware. This way, all routes controlled by the router instance will receive the headers.

For example:

```js
//...
var router = express.Router();

// middleware for all routes
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // inject default headers
  res.header('cache-control', 'private, max-age=0');
  res.header('expires', new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString());
  next();
});

// all routes below will now inherit 
// the middleware's default headers
router.get('/users', function(req, res){
   // I will return the user list, with default headers
   // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out that none of these answer actually answer the question; the question is specifically relating to render responses; e.g. for an app like:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
router.use('/test.json', (req, res) => res.json({ test: 'hi' });
router.use('/test.html', (req, res) => res.render('test'));
```

It's not clear how to add headers (e.g. CSP headers, which can be very verbose) *only* to your HTML responses. Express doesn't have a hook to specifically do that. The only option at the moment is to organize your code so you don't have to, e.g.

```
app.use(jsonRouter);
app.use(htmlRouter);
```

...which allows you to do as some of the other answers suggest, and add generic middleware for setting the headers.

Comment: I think this answer was the answer we both were looking for:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48448925/6814172