# Node JS CORS module not setting Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cors, preflight

Am trying to set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header globally in Node Js using the CORS module configuration like this

```
`var cors = require('cors');
 var corsOptions = {
     origin: true,
     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost:1550'
     'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
 };

app.use(cors(corsOptions));`
```

This doesn't seem to work so I set it too for the route am trying to set a preflight response for. I set it like this

```
`router.options('/login', cors(corsOptions));`
```

I check on Chrome Developer Tools and I see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is set but not `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`. I need this header since I have set `withCredentials = true` in Angular.

Why is Node JS not setting Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header yet it sets the others?

I know this because am getting the following error in console

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.localhost:1550/api/v1/auth/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:1550' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are not setting the configurations correctly. As in the documentation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options

```
 var corsOptions = {
 origin: 'localhost:1550',
 credentials : true
}
```

this will set the credentials header. As Origin sets Access-Control-Allow-Origin and credentials sets Access-Control-Allow-Credentials.

Comment: Thanks, I now realize that I had not gone throw the documentation thoroughly

Answer (score 1):

You left out the details about what library if any you are using.  Is it express?  Post the full code.

Since you are just specifying the headers explicitly anyway you can drop the cors module.
You can adapt this answer 
[In Node.js/Express, how do I automatically add this header to every "render" response?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6661151/281920)

Comment: Am using Express, that code is pretty much it in terms of what I have written to handle the preflight request