# CORS not allowing access

Tags: node.js, cors

I have looked at and troubleshot with many different posts on stack overflow of people having similar or the same issue, however, no solutions seem to work for me.

I keep getting the error
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/email?email=j' from origin 'https://mai...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I thought adding `app.use(cors());` would fix it, but the problem persists.

```
const path = require("path");
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

var userController = require("./controllers/userController.js");
var emailController = require("./controllers/emailController.js");

var app = express();

app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect(
  "redactedForStackOverflow",
  { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true },
  err => {
    if (!err) console.log("MongoDB connection succeeded...");
    else
      console.log(
        "Error in DB connection : " + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)
      );
  }
);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "angular")));

var port = 3000;

app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () =>
  console.log("Server started at port : " + port)
);

app.use("/users", userController);
app.use("/email", emailController);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "angular", "index.html"));
});

module.exports = app;
```

**EDIT**

Adding service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/operator/toPromise';

import { User } from './user.model';
import { UserComponent } from '../user/user.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  selectedUser: User;
  users: User[];
  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/users';
  codeSentIn;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  postUser(users: User) {
    const codeOnItsWay = this.codeSentIn;
    this.resetCode();
    return this.http.post<any>(this.baseURL, {users, codeOnItsWay});
  }

  resetCode() {
    this.codeSentIn = '';
  }

  getUserList() {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL);
  }

  getSpecificUser(id) {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.baseURL + '/' + id);
  }

  findPositionInLine(email) {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.baseURL + '/positionInLine/' + email);
  }

  getUserForLogin(email) {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/login/' + email);
  }

  sendEmailToCheck(emailToCheck) {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/email', { params: { email: emailToCheck }});
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't adding CORS headers to an OPTIONS route allow browsers to access my API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/why-doesnt-adding-cors-headers-to-an-options-route-allow-browsers-to-access-my)

Comment: @Raymond If you scroll down to the post below the one marked as the answer, it displays what I'm trying to do

Comment: Can you show the client-side code making the request so we can see exactly what the request is.  Also, `app.use(cors());` is not sufficient for all possible cross origin requests.  We need to know what's in the actual request because you probably have to do more than that and support an OPTIONS request handler.  If you look in the network tab of the chrome debugger and the actual request that's being sent you will learn a bunch.  If you share that with us, then we can help you better.

Comment: @RyanSoderberg but I can't see you set the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', if you look in the second part of it, you need to add `res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` to set header in your request

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, I've added my services from the client side to the OP

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache?

Comment: Which request in that client code?

Comment: @jfriend00   `sendEmailToCheck()` , though it is the only one I've tried so far
  }

Comment: have you tried the white list option from cors ?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: OK, if I were debugging this, I would next look at the network tab in the Chrome debugger and see exactly what the client is sending to the server for that request (including headers) and then see exactly what the server is responding with.  And, I'd look to see if the browser is sending an OPTIONS pre-flight request instead of the GET request.  And, we could help you better if you shared all that with us.

Comment: @Raymond Your deleted response worked!

Comment: @RyanSoderberg ah nice, i have recovered it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update:** possible missing cors option:

```
 var corsOptions = {
 origin: 'localhost:3000',
 credentials : true
}
```

as mentioned from here : [Node JS CORS module not setting Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468738/node-js-cors-module-not-setting-access-control-allow-credentials-header)

Alternatively, Remove app.use(cors());

You can manually add header in all your requests :

```
app.use((req, res,next) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});
```

Just add the above code block before

```
app.use("/users", userController);
app.use("/email", emailController);
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "angular", "index.html"));
});
```

Comment: That's what `app.use(cors())` already does.  It already adds the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header.  That's part of the point of using it.