# Set custom header when using res.render

Tags: node.js, express, render

I'm using express.js's res.render function and I met some issue to set custom headers, I'm tried 4 kind of method and all failed

here is my code

#### Method 1

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain; charset=utf-8'});
  next()
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.locals.text="hello";  
  res.render('index');
});
```

It has a error log with this code: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

---

#### Method 2 (example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661151/in-node-js-express-how-do-i-automatically-add-this-header-to-every-render-res))

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain; charset=utf-8'});
  next()
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.locals.text="hello";
  res.render('index');
});
```

the code comes with the error: `TypeError: field.toLowerCase is not a function`

---

#### Method 3

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8'});
  res.locals.text="hello";
  res.render('index');
});
```

the code also has error: `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

---

That's all the ways I can thought and find but still can't resolve, is there any ways to set custom header (especially encoding type) with res.render?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To set custom response header with `res.render`, you can use `res.set()`. Here is an example code:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.set({'Content-Type': 'application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8'});
  res.locals.text="hello";
  res.render('index');
});
```

Please check Express [document](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set) for more details about `res.set()`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an header for your response, you can use setHeader method on `http.ServerResponse` object.

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res) {      
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');      
    res.write(headerStr);
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: It works, but notice i'm using express framework, and also I'm using express's rendering function