# NodeJS/Express: How to set custom headers to all res.render but not res.send?

Tags: node.js, express

I have multiple middlewares on my Express server. I want to set the same custom headers to all `res.render`s. However, I don't want them to be sent with the `res.send`s.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661151/in-node-js-express-how-do-i-automatically-add-this-header-to-every-render-res).  However, doing this will set headers to all responses sent by the server including both `res.render`s and `res.send`s.

Is there a way to affect all `res.render`s  without affecting `res.send`s ?

Thank you!

Comment: The only way I see this working is if you specify a middleware like in the answer above, but you conditionally check whether or not to set stuff. What is your use case?

Comment: @FranciscoMateo yeah, the conditionally part is the part I'm trying to avoid; I currently have about 40 `res.render`s  and 40 `res.send`s .  I was trying to avoid the risk of maybe making a mistake when going trough them one by one. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way will be overriding the `res.render` method in a top middleware and when called you set your desired headers and call the original `render` method like this:

```
// top middleware
app.use(function overrideRender(req, res, next) {
    const originalRender = res.render;

    res.render = function customRender() {
        // set your headers here

        originalRender.apply(res, arguments);
    };

    next();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is this part `originalRender.apply(res, arguments);` doing?  `originalRender` is `res.render`, so what is `res.render.apply` ?  Thanks

Comment: `originalRender.apply(res, arguments);` is doing the following:

- The `res` argument is being passed to as the `this` context to not break the original implementation.
- The `arguments` argument is just to pass-through all the provided arguments when `res.render(arg1, arg2, argn)` was called.

Take a look at the official documentation for apply here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: I think your last comment is missing some text

Answer (score 1):

The [app.use()](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use) method can accept an array of end points as argument, You could group all routes (that contain `res.render` method) inside an array and call a specified middleware when the users reach one of them:

```
var routes = [
    '/route/1/',
    '/route/2/',
    '/route/3/',
];

app.use( routes, function (req, res, next) {

    res.setHeader('header' , 'value' );

    next();

});
```

Comment: Alright, but won't work if a route has both a `res.render` and a `res.send` :D