# Node js Express CORS headers are set but still getting error

Tags: node.js, express, cors

In an express app there is a middleware setting the headers like this

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', [
        'Accept',
        'Authorization',
        'Content-Type',
        'Origin',
        'X-Requested-With'
    ].join(', '))
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', [
        'DELETE',
        'GET',
        'HEAD',
        'OPTIONS',
        'PATCH',
        'POST',
        'PUT'
    ].join(', '))
    next()
})
```

But when doing a request I still get an error

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the [Express CORS package](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html). It should handle adding the CORS headers for you.

Once installed, it would be used like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

var cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

// routes go here
```

Otherwise, your implementation seems fine as per [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56119130/5496859) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6661431/5496859).